# Android Hello Map View problems on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview

I'm trying to run the Android Hello Map View tutorial app on the Android emulator. The Google Map view displays, but the tiles are blank.

Judging by the errors below (taken from LogCat) the app is unable to connect to the internet. The web browser on the emulator connects without problems. I've also double-checked the API key.

I'm using the 1.5 Google APIs SDK, from Eclipse Galileo, on Windows XP SP3, behind a corporate firewall.

I've tried two methods to add proxy information:

1. Add -http-proxy http://www.foo.co.uk:80 to Additional Emulator Command Line Options in the Target Page in Debug Configurations.
2. Remove settings in 1. and add proxy information at Home > Menu > Settings > Wireless Controls > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names.

Neither seems to help.

Any other ideas? Should I be adding proxy information within the app? If so, how?

Sam Dutton

---

AMENDMENT: internet permission has been added to the manifest application element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

```
12-23 16:43:31.624: INFO/System.out(717): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-23 16:43:31.828: INFO/System.out(717): debugger has settled (1480)
12-23 16:43:32.299: ERROR/ActivityThread(717): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-23 16:43:33.738: INFO/MapActivity(717): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-23 16:43:33.738: ERROR/MapActivity(717): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-23 16:43:34.879: DEBUG/dalvikvm(717): GC freed 4012 objects / 232976 bytes in 97ms
12-23 16:43:37.818: INFO/ActivityManager(565): Displayed activity com.bbc.HelloMapView/.HelloMapView: 8939 ms
12-23 16:43:38.408: DEBUG/dalvikvm(717): GC freed 8198 objects / 604808 bytes in 90ms
12-23 16:43:38.888: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:40.488: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:42.097: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:43.307: DEBUG/dalvikvm(612): GC freed 4040 objects / 229536 bytes in 123ms
12-23 16:43:43.789: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:45.387: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:46.978: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:48.428: DEBUG/dalvikvm(656): GC freed 2771 objects / 170824 bytes in 234ms
12-23 16:43:48.708: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:50.298: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:51.898: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:53.277: DEBUG/dalvikvm(717): GC freed 5333 objects / 338584 bytes in 140ms
12-23 16:43:53.408: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:53.447: DEBUG/dalvikvm(636): GC freed 2913 objects / 165264 bytes in 244ms
12-23 16:43:56.527: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:43:58.329: DEBUG/dalvikvm(610): GC freed 3249 objects / 193992 bytes in 122ms
12-23 16:43:59.169: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
12-23 16:44:02.518: INFO/InetAddress(717): Unknown host www.google.com, throwing UnknownHostException
```

Comment: I get unknown host exceptions every now and then. Restarting the emulator (not just the app!) has always done the trick, tho. I take it you've tried this already...?

Comment: Yeah -- tried restarting the emulator (and Eclipse, and my PC!)

Comment: I have a similar problem, I don't get any unknown host errors only the 

03-01 17:00:50.561: ERROR/MapActivity(3112): Couldn't get connection factory client

is the same. I have the same output on my mobile phone too.

Comment: I had the same issue and it turned out (for whatever reason) only to be an API Key problem, I somehow generated a false key. Team mate just sent his debug.keystore and his API Key over and know I can see the tiles. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug:  [Issue 3764: Google Maps fails via mandatory web proxy](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3764).

Answer (score 4):

Did the same thing, moved the "" above the "

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".HelloMapView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: thanks, put the INTERNET permission out of the application tag solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

are you setting the internet permission in the manifest file??

I am sure you must have just checking:)

Comment: good suggestion, but yes, I have set internet permission -- added amendment to question

Answer (score 1):

for me I put the permission in the wrong place in Manifest file. It shouldn't be within application node, instead it should be at the same level as application node..